# Receiving HTTP error 503 on Azure but works locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have an Azure Function of type Queue Trigger hosted on Azure with App Service Plan on B1.

That function makes an HTTP request to a website and downloads the HTML. When I debug the function locally and add messages to the queue everything works fine, but when I deploy it and run it on the Azure environment then it gives a 503 error.

This error is consistent with a specific website, other websites work just fine.

I first thought that the problem was with the library that I used to make the HTTP request, but I tried HttpClient, Refit, RestSharp, and they all have the same result. I also tried to get the HttpClient using the dependency injection as described on Microsoft docs but the error is the same.

After many tries I concluded that the code is not the problem, I connected to Azure Console (Development Tools) and run the curl command with the -I parameter to check the HTTP status, the result was 503, on my computer when I run the curl command, it gives me status 200.

Comment: It could be that the site you're trying to "scrape" is well aware of Azure IP's and has whitelisted them for blocking.

Comment: @lopezbertoni I don't think is configuration because of curl test that I did, which has nothing to do with code or configuration

Comment: @Skin I don't know why I didn't though about this, yeah is a very logical posibility that I didn't think about

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Almis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3546760/almis) and [Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Website that you are trying to work with is well aware of Azure IPs and are getting blocked. This is resulting in 503 errors.